# Monitor progress while loading video using Transferable in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using this approach:

[SwiftUi how can I load selected video from item identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74202070/swiftui-how-can-i-load-selected-video-from-item-identifier)

To load a selected video from the photos picker. Everything works. The problem is that I am not sure how to show the user the progress as the asset is loading.

The larger the video the more the user has to wait without having any idea how far along the import is.

How can I show a progress of the loading process so the user can know how far along the loading is?

Comment: Hi zumzum, did you resolve it ?

Comment: I have not. I am still using NSItemProvider instead. SwiftUI still not there... not sure how to do it with Transferable